# WordPress filter to stop rendering site

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site that has content (pages) that I'm querying via the REST API. However, I'd like to not render the pages on the actual WordPress URL.

I vaguely remember that there's a function I can add to a filter in my functions.php to prevent the rendering, without making the content private (I still want the REST API to be available publicly). Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a simple enough solution that I'm happy with:

```php
function private_site() {
    wp_die('No page found.', 404);
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'private_site' );
```

Comment: Yea, same idea, mine is just gives you more control.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like putting your site into like a **Maintenance Mode** expect for users that has a [specified roles](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/)?

If so, just add this snippet to your **functions.php**

```php
function disable_my_site() {
  // check if the current logged in user has a specified role like edit_theme_options.
  // Or no user is logged in. See all roles in the link above.
  if( !current_user_can('edit_theme_options') || !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_die('Add some message to show if you like. HTML is accepted.');
  }
}
add_action('get_header', 'disable_my_site', 999);

// Add this if you like to disable REST API too
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'disable_my_site', 999 );
```

Similarly please note that you can disable all or specific pages or blog posts etc..